# trying to access an external JSON file using netwonsoft in mvc4 c#

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, methods, json.net

I'm trying to read an external json to display data on screen.  What am I doing worng here?

```
public void QuarterlyReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JObject qData1 = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"~/json/quarterlyData.json"));

        // read JSON directly from a file
        using (StreamReader file = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"~/json/quarterlyData.json"))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
    {
        JObject Qdata2 = (JObject) JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
    }
        string Qdata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(qData1);
    }

    public async Task<FileStreamResult> Index()
    {

        var _reportingService = new ReportingService("https://mysite.jsreportonline.net", "myemail@gmail.com", "password");
        var report = await _reportingService.RenderAsync("VyxOYwH7Ze", new { Qdata });
        //add the stream to be used by browser
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        //copy whatever JS is sending to us
        report.Content.CopyTo(ms);
        //start at content point
        ms.Position = 0;
        //send this to browser
        return File(ms, report.ContentType.MediaType);

    }
```

I can't seem to get the vaule into the variable Qdata.  What is it that I am doing wrong in the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line where you declare Qdata:

```
string Qdata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(qData1);
```

is not in the same scope as this line:

```
var report = await _reportingService.RenderAsync("VyxOYwH7Ze", new { Qdata });
```

Comment: But putting that in the same scope tells me qData1 does not exist in the current context.  Is this because the method is not a public static class so I can't access it?

Comment: I would assume that's because Qdata1 is *also* not in the scope of Index(). Correct?

Comment: Accept answer please.

Comment: Wouldn't let me before.  Now it just did.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem was that

```
JObject qData1 = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"~/json/quarterlyData.json"));
```

And

```
string Qdata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(qData1);
```

Needed to be in the same scope as

```
var report = await _reportingService.RenderAsync("VyxOYwH7Ze", new { Qdata });
```